# proxyBeanMethods exception in SCDF 2.2.1

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run a very simple stream app in `SCDF 2.2.1` with `minikube` but I'm getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration] is declared as an @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].

After googling that error, I found that `proxyBeanMethods` is a new feature in `Spring Boot 2.2` but `SCDF 2.2.1` runs `Spring Boot 2.1.6`.

Here is my processor code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class MyApplication {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
  @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
  public String check(String payload) {

  log.info(payload);

      return payload;
  }
}
```

It seems that there is some kind of incompatibility but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my versions to :

- `Spring Boot 2.1.6`
- `Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR4` which uses `Spring Cloud Stream 2.1.4`

and now my stream is working

Answer (score 0):

There could be incompatibility issues if you mix Boot versions between SCDF and the streaming/task applications.

You would want to switch SCDF to [2.3.0.RC2](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases/tag/v2.3.0.RC2) since this version builds on the Spring Boot 2.2.x foundation. The 2.3.0.GA is tracked to be released this week, as well.

Comment: Thank you ! I just see that there is a new helm chart with SCDF 2.3. This could solve my issue too

Comment: Correct. It'd be recommended to be on the latest GA releases of Stream and SCDF. They are at 3.0 and 2.3 respectively. As you pointed out, we have updated the Helm chart to support the latest SCDF release, as well.